# OpenGL renders triangle instead of quad

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm currently trying to render a texture to a fullscreen `QWindow` (Qt 5.9.1).
Since the textures were all black I wanted to make sure that the indeces were right by telling the fragment shader to render all pixels in red, but apparently a mistake happened here.
Instead of a quad I get a red triangle in the upper left corner of the screen.
I can't see the mistake I made with my code, so I ask you to look over my code.
Also what could be a reason to only get black textures, even though the textures I upload with `glTexImage2D` look fine and there are no errors in `glGetError`.
Thanks in advance.

Initialisation of OpenGL context and QWindow:

```
int i;
for( i=0;i<QApplication::screens().size();i++ )
{
    if(QApplication::screens().at(i)->name().compare(szScreenName)==0)
        break;
}
if(i==QApplication::screens().size())
    i--;

setGeometry(QApplication::screens().at(i)->availableGeometry());
showFullScreen();

setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
QSurfaceFormat fmt;
fmt.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::SingleBuffer);
fmt.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLES);
setFormat(fmt);
_pContext = new QOpenGLContext(this);
_pContext->setFormat(fmt);
//_pContext->setShareContext(QOpenGLContext::globalShareContext());
_pContext->create();

QObject::connect( this, &DLP::postRenderSignal, this, &DLP::render );

_pContext->makeCurrent(this);
initializeOpenGLFunctions();

//_pTexManager = new TextureManager(QOpenGLContext::globalShareContext()->functions());
_pTexManager = new TextureManager(this);

char* szVertexShader =                          "#version 110\n"
                                                "attribute vec4 a_Position;\n"
                                                "attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;\n"
                                                "varying   vec2 v_TexCoord;\n"
                                                "void main()\n"
                                                "{\n"
                                                "    gl_Position = a_Position;\n"
                                                "    v_TexCoord = a_TexCoord;\n"
                                                "}\n";
char* szFragmentShader =                        "#version 110\n"
                                                "precision mediump float;\n"
                                                "varying vec2 v_TexCoord;\n"
                                                "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;\n"
                                                "void main()\n"
                                                "{\n"
                                                "    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);//texture2D( u_Texture, v_TexCoord );\n"
                                                "}\n";

//_nProgram = linkShader(QOpenGLContext::globalShareContext()->functions(), szVertexShader, szFragmentShader);
_nProgram = linkShader(this, szVertexShader, szFragmentShader);

if(_nProgram!=0)
{
    _nShaderSamplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation(_nProgram,"u_Texture");
    _nShaderTextureLoc = glGetAttribLocation(_nProgram,"a_TexCoord");
    _nShaderPositionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(_nProgram,"a_Position");
}

glGenBuffers(2, _pBuffers );

static const unsigned short pIndexData[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _pBuffers[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pIndexData), pIndexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

static const float pPosBuffer[20] = {
        -1,   1,   0,    0, 0,
         1,   1,   0,    1, 0,
        -1,  -1,   0,    0, 1,
         1   -1,   0,    1, 1,
};
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _pBuffers[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 20*4, pPosBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Render code (DLP::render):

```
if (!isExposed() || !_pContext)
    return;

_pContext->makeCurrent(this);

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0,0,m_nWidth,m_nHeight);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glUseProgram(_nProgram);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _pBuffers[0]);
// Load the vertex position
glVertexAttribPointer(_nShaderPositionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_nShaderPositionLoc);
// Load the texture coordinate
//glVertexAttribPointer(_nShaderTextureLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, (void*)(3 * 4));
//glEnableVertexAttribArray(_nShaderTextureLoc);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _pTexManager->getTexture(key));
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glUniform1i(_nShaderSamplerLoc, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _pBuffers[1]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(_nShaderPositionLoc);
//glDisableVertexAttribArray(_nShaderTextureLoc);

glFinish();

_pContext->swapBuffers(this);
```

Edit:
Furthermore this problem only happens when i have multiple OpenGL contextes in Qt, e.g. 4 Framebuffer objects, the QML Scenegraph and this QWindow, so it might be a problem with how Qt handles OpenGL contextes.

Comment: Quick shot in the dark... your `glDawElements`, shouldn't that use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES`? since `GL_TRIANGLES` expects 3 verts per triangle, and your only give it 4(3 for the first and 1 for the last)?  where a strip would use 2 of the previous vertex?

Comment: You're right about that, I didn't update that code segment. The error is still there with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP.

Comment: I think you vertex order is wrong for a strip.  You're going top right to bottom left. You need bottom, left -> top, left -> bottom, right -> top right - a zig-zag.

Comment: changing the vertex order didn't help. I have a feeling, that Qt messes up the opengl state machine and for that reason it doesn't work properly.
I have it running perfectly in one configurtion, where i have only one opengl context and when i have multiple contextes i run into the described problem.

Comment: @Krustenkaese Qt can't mess up no state for you, but you can ;)  . Check better what Eddge  said above.

Comment: @MichaelIvanov I am aware of the indexing needed for the glDrawElements flags. I had been using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP from the beginning and thought about changing it to GL_TRIANGLES to see wether that could help. It didn't and i changed it back, though when i first posted the code here i forgot to change the flag back. i also tried the order Robinson suggested (Vertex order 2,0,3,1) but that didn't help either. I'll continue to investigate. The reason why i blame Qt is, that the very same code works in an isolated program perfectly fine, but in my main project with mutiple contextes it doesn't.

Comment: I did mess up :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, question is solved:
Apparently I had some problem with my texture data, which did have strange alpha data, so with enabled blend function it didn't render the textures.
Also the reason for the rectangle not being rendered correctly was a sign error in one of the indeces.
Btw: [Vogl](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/vogl) is a very useful tool to look at the OpenGL statemachine to debug applications.